# Angular 2 opening a static page

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have angular 2 project. I want to open static help files available on server in new window.  I tried `window.open(help/index.html)`. 
It navigates to the page but throws error about route not found. 
I have also tried to run above code outside angular zone but makes no difference. 
I suspect as browser location changes angular detects it in next change detection cycle and try to route to that URL. 
What could be done to achieve this.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate away from your app?

Comment: Not exactly. I am opening help content of app in a separate tab/window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and leverage the `name` parameter of the [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method which is the equivalent of the `target` attribute in anchor tags.

```js
window.open("help/index.html", "_blank");
```

---

> working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K5gaUzYx6aSLq9HxHowi?p=preview) example

Comment: Thanks. I tried that earlier and it is navigating to new page without this argument as well but if you look in dev tools you see a lot of error coming from router.  I am not sure if plunkr will be suppress that error so try on download plunkr.  I will give it another shot and let you know.

Comment: Thanks this worked. The catch was i was just specifying window.open("help", "_blank"); and assuming it will auto redirect to index page but angular was treating it as route change rather than static page navigation which forced all those error,

Comment: if I try opening from ngOnInit() of app module it goes into an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

The way that I got around the error is to wrap the `window.open` in a timeout. This allows for the window open to run after the angular code finishes. Normally you don't want to use timeouts inside of your app but since this is opening a new window at a new location that won't use the same instance of your app it should be okay.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  window.open("./README.md", "_blank");
});
```

> [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0joca5j4uJQIB23ps1d9?p=preview)