# is it possible to angular 2 html file, instead of component?

Tags: html, angular, routes

I have appCmponent.ts :

```
@Routes([
  {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '/home', component:  HomeComponent},
  {path: '/graph', component:  GraphComponent},
])
```

What if i don't want to load GraphComponent and I just want to load html file with  inside.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to wrap your HTML in a component. There is no way around.

Comment: What's you use case?

Comment: just want to make simple graph drowing like here: http://bl.ocks.org/jhb/5955887 and place all js code in html.

Comment: You could use a single component for multiple routes that allows to pass some HTML and shows it using `<div [innerHTML]="somePassedHTML">` but I don't know what would make sense how to pass the HTML to the component.

Comment: I think I'l create separate component with it's html template, and in the template I'll place a   js script. will it work? I curious if I place libraries and script in the template will it run...

Comment: No, you can't put JS in the template. Just put it in the components class instead. `<script>` tags are removed from templates.

Comment: is thee other ways to open html page from my app?  Let say i type localhost:8080/graph.html  and it opens separate html file.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "open"

Comment: Sorry for my junior explanation. All i want is when i type localhost:8080/graph.html   it should load static page graph.html. I don't want to create GraphComponent.
i think i will use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858849/angular-2-opening-a-static-page

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. You can always load static HTML this way if the server provides it at that URL. How is Angular involved here? You could show HTML in an `<iframe>` (again inside a component). Just to throw an idea because I don't seem to understand the actual problem yet.

Comment: I've made some misunderstanding. I sought it's not possible to load static page in SPA. only components template. Now it's ok!  And thank you for always response. your advices helps me a lot!!!

Comment: If you load static page, them it is not an SPA. You can navigate from an SPA to a static page and back though.